# How to draw a pictue in python like the following

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to  draw a pictue in python like this [enter image description here

[image]

I have already draw the heatmap.But I want to know how to add the star markers which denotes the selected data points on initial and boundary conditions

Answer (score 0):

If you create your heatmap with `plt.imshow`, then you can add a scatter plot. Maybe add the code snippet which you use to draw the heatmap for clarity.

Here is an example code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Plot the underlying heatmap
a = np.random.random((10, 10))
plt.imshow(a, cmap='hot')
# Plot the data points as scatter
xs = np.random.random((30,1)) * 10
ys = np.random.random((30,1)) * 10
plt.scatter(xs, ys, marker="*")
plt.show()
```

[Here you can see the resulting plot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdDIc.png)